# ConflictError: database conflict error

Tags: plone, zope

Can anybody explain me that error - and how I can repair it?

We use:

- Plone 4
- Zope 2.12.19
- ZEO
- zodb-temporary-storage

**Error Log**

```
Site Error

An error was encountered while publishing this resource.

Sorry, a site error occurred.

Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 239, in publish_module_standard
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 197, in publish
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 197, in publish
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 197, in publish
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 173, in publish
Module plone.app.linkintegrity.monkey, line 17, in zpublisher_exception_hook_wrapper
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 135, in publish
Module Zope2.App.startup, line 291, in commit
Module transaction._manager, line 93, in commit
Module transaction._transaction, line 322, in commit
Module transaction._transaction, line 419, in _commitResources
Module ZODB.Connection, line 767, in tpc_vote
Module ZEO.ClientStorage, line 1068, in tpc_vote
Module ZEO.ClientStorage, line 905, in _check_serials

ConflictError: database conflict error (oid 0x08, class Products.Transience.Transience.Length2, serial this txn started with 0x0394fddba7126fbb 2012-03-08 07:23:39,157504, serial currently committed 0x0394fddbb0a4cb22 2012-03-08 07:23:41,400873)

Troubleshooting Suggestions

The URL may be incorrect.
The parameters passed to this resource may be incorrect.
A resource that this resource relies on may be encountering an error.

For more detailed information about the error, please refer to the error log.

If the error persists please contact the site maintainer. Thank you for your patience.
```

I tried to repaire the Data.fs without any errors...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Database conflict errors can f.e. occur, if a transaction couldn't be completed. Is this a dev- or a production-instance? Since when does the error occur and what changes did you do shortly before?

Comment: It's a production server
Errors occurs randomly - when users opens a browser-view, a simple folder or an Editor works on it...

Comment: @user966660 - any luck on this issue? I'm dealing with the exact same problem - it seems it's something related to authentication/session (0x08 oid is in the temp storage of session manager)

Answer (score 4):

Conflict Errors occur when two users try to update the same object (often one that is part of a catalogue data structure) at the same time and the system cannot resolve the conflict. You should ensure that your ZEO server includes all of the eggs from the Zope instance to ensure you have all the conflict resolution code.

If you are seeing these on simple views, then it probably means you have some code that is updating the database on rendering that view. This is not a good idea with ZODB.

Comment: _ensure that your ZEO server includes all of the eggs from the Zope instance_ - Is that required? Didn't find any documentation for that. [Zope2 wiki](http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/ZEOZopeEnterpriseObjects) says: Note: Data.fs is kept in the ZEO server, all products are installed in the client.

Comment: you were right, found it in buildout docs of plone.recipe.zeoserver - _"eggs - Set if you need to include other packages as eggs e.g. for making application code available on the ZEO server side for performing conflict resolution (through the _p_resolveConflict() handler)."_ and there is such a handler in Products.Transience, now part of Zope 2.12 egg

Comment: @Laurence Rowe - When you say "some code that updates the database on rendering that view" do you mean ZODB ?

Comment: @Ravi yes, by database I mean the ZODB.